# TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'css' w/ Express.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

Attempting to change the CSS of a div element in jQuery via Chrome Console and getting this response:

```
$('#first-block').css('color','green')
TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'css'
```

However when I call

```
$('#first-block')
```

The console returns the div and it's contents

I'm using Express.js w/ MongoDB, utilising the Express cache middleware.

Comment: Are you using jQuery no conflict? (if so, replace `$` with `jQuery`)

Comment: In the browser console, what is the value of `$ === jQuery`?

Comment: $ === jQuery
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're not loading jQuery correctly. Make sure that you've loaded jQuery in your haed section, and that your code in wrapped in the appropriate way, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#first-block').css('color','green');
    });
</script>
```